# Sort List of string arrays by first element

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I want to sort a list of string arrays by first element in each array element of same list, in reverse order, so 2, 1, 0

Here's what i tried so far:

```
List<String[]> array = new ArrayList<>();

String[] arr1 = {"0", "1/1"};
String[] arr2 = {"1", "1/2"};
String[] arr3 = {"2", "1/4"};

array.add(arr1);
array.add(arr2);
array.add(arr3);

Comparator<String[]> byFirstElement = 
    (String[] array1, String[] array2) -> Integer.parseInt(array1[0]) - 
                                           Integer.parseInt(array2[0]);


List<String[]> result = array.stream()
        .sorted(array,byFirstElement) // error here
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The problem is that at sorted line i have an error highlighted, saying:
"sorted(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator

Comment: It should be `.sorted(byFirstElement)`. Remove the `array` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stream.sorted()` takes a comparator (in addition to the overload that takes no argument). So all you need is `...sorted(byFirstElement)...` (the stream sorts its elements)

Note that your comparison logic won't sort in descending order, so you either need to change it to

```
Comparator<String[]> byFirstElement = 
    (array1, array2) -> Integer.parseInt(array2[0]) - Integer.parseInt(array1[0]);
                        //reversed
```

or reverse it when calling `sorted()`:

```
....sorted(byFirstElement.reversed())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code with the [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-) method as follows:

```java
List<String[]> list = List.of(
        new String[]{"0", "1/1"},
        new String[]{"1", "1/2"},
        new String[]{"2", "1/4"});

List<String[]> sorted = list.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
                arr -> Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// output
sorted.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[2, 1/4]
[1, 1/2]
[0, 1/1]
```

---

<sup>See also:

• [How to sort by a field of class with its own comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65580486/14940971)

• [Sorting 2D array of strings in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65681972/14940971)</sup>