# How to sort by a field of class with its own comparator?

Tags: java, list, sorting, object, comparator

I have a sample class, say `Country`:

```java
class Country {
    public String name;
    public int population;
    public Flag flag;  
    ...                                                                        
}
```

I have this `Flag` class defined somewhere else

```java
class Flag {
    String id;
    int pixel;
    ...
}
```

Now I create a separate comparator DefaultFlagRankingComparator() that can sort Flag by id. How can I sort a list of Country by Flag id, using this DefaultFlagRankingComparator()?

Answer (score 4):

You can invoke the compare method of the `Comparator` with the flag field of each country.

```java
DefaultFlagRankingComparator flagComparator =
        new DefaultFlagRankingComparator();
Collections.sort(countries, (a, b) ->
        flagComparator.compare(a.getFlag(), b.getFlag()));
```

You could also use [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-) to create a `Comparator` using a key extracting function and a `Comparator` that compares those keys (as suggested by [Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman)).

```java
DefaultFlagRankingComparator flagComparator =
        new DefaultFlagRankingComparator();
Collections.sort(countries,
        Comparator.comparing(Country::getFlag, flagComparator));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can compare `String` values of ids using predefined methods:

   ```java
   Arrays.sort(countries, (c1, c2) -> Objects.compare(
           c1.getFlag().getId(), c2.getFlag().getId(),
           Comparator.naturalOrder()));
   ```

   ```java
   Arrays.sort(countries, Comparator.comparing(country ->
           country.getFlag().getId(), Comparator.naturalOrder()));
   ```
2. You can specify a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

   ```java
   Arrays.sort(countries, Comparator
           .comparing(country -> country.getFlag(),
                   new DefaultFlagRankingComparator()));
   ```

   ```java
   static class DefaultFlagRankingComparator implements Comparator<Flag> {
       @Override
       public int compare(Flag o1, Flag o2) {
           return Objects.compare(o1.getId(), o2.getId(),
                   Comparator.naturalOrder());
       }
   }
   ```
3. You can implement interface [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in the `Flag` class:

   ```java
   Arrays.sort(countries, Comparator.comparing(Country::getFlag));
   ```

   ```java
   static class Flag implements Comparable<Flag> {
       String id;

       public String getId() { return id; }

       @Override
       public int compareTo(Flag that) {
           return Objects.compare(this.getId(), that.getId(),
                   Comparator.naturalOrder());
       }
   }
   ```